# How to use \rightmark or \leftmark?

Tags: header-footer

If I just use

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

everything goes well. But once I use

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rightmark}
```

The output becomes[image]

but no errors are alarmed. Can someone help? Many thanks!

Comment: You have to show the code that generates the marks, otherwise we can't diagnose this. Are you using `\chaptermark` in your code? Please give a complete but minimal example document (MWE).

Comment: For book class the chapter is in \leftmark and and section in \rightmark.